# Ubiquity can't detect my main hard disk with WIndows 8 installed

Tags: installation, windows-8, ubiquity

I'm running Ubuntu Live to see if it functions well along side of Win 8.1.  For some reason the main drive is invisible to Ubuntu. That is, a 500 GB drive shows at the Launcher but reflects 0 bytes, 0bytes.  It won't open in Ubuntu.  Any Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: Idea: Stop the hate speech. [Learn how to ask questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) [Learn again.](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem here (as I just discovered on my newly-upgraded-to-Windows-8.1 laptop) is that when Windows 8.1 shuts down, it does not correctly dismount the system disk.  Therefore, the ntfs partition is marked as "unsafe".  When we try to open that ntfs volume by clicking on the ubiquity icon, the mount attempt fails silently.  If it at least gave an error message, it would be better.

I was able to mount my Windows volume by using the command line, and mounting it Read-Only.
This is not ideal, but better than nothing.  Ubiquity should really warn and then mount read only rather than be silent.

The correct answer to the problem is to shut down Windows correctly.  I have tried three different methods (each of which worked on Windows 8) but have not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Note:  this is not a duplicate of any of the installation or boot questions.  This problem raises its ugly head only after the dual boot installation has been successfully accomplished.]